# What's the difference between + and = when using chmod?

Tags: command-line, chmod

I read everything about [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod), but I don't get something. If I write `chmod u=rwx file` this "affects" me for all rights on the file, and if I write `chmod u+rwx file` this "adds" me all the rights on the file, but what is the difference between `+` and `=`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you're specifying all the read, write and execute bits, there's no difference.

The difference comes if you only specify *some* of the bits:

```
$ umask 022
$ touch afile ; ls -l afile
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Aug 21 11:23 afile
$ chmod u+x afile; ls -l afile
-rwxr--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Aug 21 11:23 afile*
$ chmod u=x afile; ls -l afile
---xr--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Aug 21 11:23 afile*
```

Comment: ok now I get it thank you very much to you and dagrha

Comment: Actually, there is a difference. The setuid bit, if set, will be unset.

Comment: Good example, could you please directly explain the difference in your answer? While it may be obvious to you, this would benefit future readers.

Answer (score 10):

from the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod):

> The operator + causes the selected file mode bits to be added to the
>   existing file mode bits of each file; - causes them to be removed; and
>   = causes them to be added and causes unmentioned bits to be removed except that a directory's unmentioned set user and group ID bits are
>   not affected.

Comment: This is the best answer, it directly answers the question.